# What does proxyexec + cagefs.server mean in the e-mail X-Source-Args?

Tags: email, proxy, spam

I've the following headers in the e-mail which I've received as spam:

```
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: /usr/sbin/proxyexec -q -d -s /var/run/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket /bin/cagefs.server 
X-Source-Dir: silvianimberg.com:/public_html/wp-content/themes/ultimatum
```

Can you explain how and why proxyexec/cagefs.server is used?

Does it indicate that the server has been hacked for spam purposes using some loophole on the webserver? Or it's a standard way of sending the e-mails through some CMSes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This header

```
X-Source-Args: /usr/sbin/proxyexec -q -d -s /var/run/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket /bin/cagefs.server
```

is standard header in email sent from shared hosting. When I search the keyword `/var/run/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket` via [SE search](http://stackexchange.com/search) , it pop up in several questions on SO and SF, indicating this header was normal.

---

I don't familiar with CageFS. But after lurking at some Google Result, CageFS appears to be some kind of container to separating user in multi user environment. It using [proxyexec](https://github.com/gstrauss/bsock/tree/master/proxyexec) to proxying command invoked from a cage to command outside its cage. Snippet from [this page](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/cagefs.html) and [this page](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/executing_by_proxy.html)

> CageFS is a virtualized file system and a set of tools to contain each user in its own 'cage'. Each customer will have its own fully functional CageFS, with all the system files, tools, etc...
>
> Some software has to run outside of CageFS to be able to complete its job. This includes such programs as passwd, sendmail, etc. CloudLInux uses proxyexec technology to accomplish such goal. You can define any program to run outside CageFS, by specifying it in `/etc/cagefs/proxy.commands`